# How do I set prifix to django contrib tables names?

Tags: python, django, django-models

HI

One of my requirement is to have prefix on all the tables of the django based project (Because db is hosted on shared server). I have used db_table Meta option to set the prefix for the tables which I have created.

Now my query is how do I set the prefix for tables provided by django.contrib.

Instead of auth_group django should create prefix_auth_group.... How do I do that?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

From reading [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/891), I would say it is not possible without a hack.